# How to display taxonomy terms of a particular vocabulary in views

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I am trying to display taxonomy terms of a particular vocabulary in views terms field, but I am lost as to how to do it. I have done the same thing in full view mode using template.php.

Answer (score 2):

**Answer revised**
Create a view of type `Node`
Add a display of type `block` or `page` according to your need
Add your desired fields(CCK) along with a field `Taxonomy: Term`
Add a filter `Taxonomy: Vocabulary` and select `is one of` operator and choose the particular vocabulary name.

This solution will include taxonomy terms associated with content node but filter according to the defined vocabulary in filter.

Comment: I already have a view which displays a particular cck, to which I would like to add the taxonomy terms of a particular vocabulary.

Comment: What is the logic to include terms with nodes, Is there any relation of nodes (containing your cck) with the terms.

Comment: The cck content type have 3 vocabularies from which a user can tag a video(cck). I want to display only a particular vocabulary terms in one of the view which has fields from the video cck and neglect the rest.